# MVCMailer + Razor + CSS woes

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Right off the bat, I am not a programmer.  It's weird, but the harder the problem either I can find the answer (Google anyone?) or figure it out (no, really, it's Google).  The easy stuff (I know this because I know)? That I have real trouble with.

I am using MVCMailer + Razor.  I got it to send out a mail (dump to c:/), and all was great. I spent some time setting up my mails (I am still toying around with the logic - maybe a future question on a different topic), and I took a break to style it.  Several explicative's (and hours later), I cannot figure this out.

First, I was converting from MVC 2 (used a tool to upgrade, pages worked, etc.).  I continued using a Helper class to bring in stylesheets at first in my _Layout.cshtml class:

1) `<head> ... <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= Url.Stylesheet("Default") %>" media="all" />...</head>`

When I pull up the *.cshtml generated mail, no styling.  NOTE: My Default.css simply imports all my other .css files (I separate out header/content/footer/etc.).  However, I tried specifically loading the .css file (Mailer.css - original, I known) that I am using for the mails.

Second, I tried the following from some popular blogs on the subject:

2) <`head> ... <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("../../Content/Default.css")" /> ... </head>`

Yes, I did `@using Namespace` for that helper. No styling in the actual e-mail.

Finally,

3) I put a `<style>` block directly in the *.cshtml file.

It worked.

I am stumped. Is it MVCMailer? Am I completely missing something?  My goal is to have more than just a text mail, nothing fancy (header/content/footer - some font styling and background color).

Comment: Solution: There is none, apparently.  It turns out that many email clients will not load any CSS.  Instead, I learned that to style the e-mail you must do it INLINE. So #3 above (putting a <style> block), seems to be the only alternative. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue with MvcMailer. Its an issue with how email clients treat the CSS files.

Even if your CSS file is rightly linked, most email clients will only use inline CSS. Check this out: http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_html/

Answer (score 0):

I would try using:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"
       type="text/css"
       href="@Url.Abs( Url.Content( "~/content/default.css" )" ) />
```

You want to make the path relative to the site root using the tilde. Also, the urls need to be absolute, not relative.  See the guide at https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Comment: Sorry, I included "../../Content/Default.css" in that second example but it was actually the last thing I tried.  It was originally "~/Content/Default.css" which is the actual location of the file.  In either event, neither worked.  And I just kept the MVC folder structure, the .css files are in the "Content" folder, not in a sub-folder.

Comment: I also noticed you included a space after the first "(" and after the last ")".  I'm thinking that was just a typo (or the way SO displays), but will try that as well. Edit: No, that did not work.

Comment: @REMESQ - I looked at the docs and the urls need to be absolute, so wrap the Content method in the Abs method.  https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide Note: I haven't used this so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Inline is the way to go.

I've had some success with  blocks within the  of the HTML, but I wouldn't want to rely upon that across the board.